# Scheduler Spring, Clustered Environment, Not Quartz

Tags: java, spring, scheduler, scheduling, quartz

I have a database with multiple rows having a date time column, i want to create a scheduler that runs every 5 minutes and reads the records from that table on the date time column and picks all records which have date lesser than current time, and executes some business logic on those records one by one in a clustered environment, and one record must be processed only once. I cannot use Quartz since that will need me to store the Job etc in another table which at present is not an option for me. PLease if you can guide me.

Comment: Hi there, please share some analytical part(DB table, data or etc) to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the info from [there](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks). In two words, add `@EnableScheduling` onto your `main()` method's class, than create a new method in some controller and add `@Scheduled` annotation on the method.